# In powder x rd, if the crystals are randomly oriented ,why then do we get Debye rings and not random patterns?

Tags: crystal-structure, x-ray-diffraction

In powder x-ray diffraction ,as I have learnt the sample is multi-crystalline.So if x-ray is diffracted through these randomly oriented crystal grains, aren't we supposed to get a random pattern?

Comment: That's because no matter how you would rotate a crystal grain, it would diffract only at certain special angles. Also, welcome to Chem.SE.

Comment: Firstly thank for your answer and warm welcome.

Comment: Can you please describe why it is so.I am not able to visualise it.

Comment: Check out this site for an exhaustive explanation of powder diffraction:- http://pd.chem.ucl.ac.uk/pdnn/powintro/powdiff.htm